# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:devDebugRuntimeClasspath'. Using insecure protocols with repositories, without

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I am using Artic fox version of Android studio. I just upgraded the Gradle version to 7.0.2 and I am getting this error.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:devDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported.
Switch Maven repository 'maven(http://maven.ideas-implemented.com/repo)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.
```

What could be done to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are using HTTP instead of https.
Search for the "http://maven.ideas-implemented.com/repo" string (Ctrl + Shift + F). Typically you would get it in the gradle file. Replace the HTTP with HTTPS (appropriate URL if need be). it should fix your problem